# Reduce latency between pod on OpenShift and VM on GCP

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud, openshift

I have a configuration where I have:

- Pods managed by OpenShift on GCP in a zone/region
- VM on GCP in same zone/region

I need to reduce as much as possible the latency between those pods and the VM on GCP.

What are the available options for that ?

My understanding is that they would need to be in same VPC but I don't know how to do that.
If you can point me to reference documentation, it would help me a lot.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for that:

- The best one is to create a sub-project in the OpenShift project that shares the same VPC. This way the machines are in the same network, so the latency is as low as possible. However, this leads to management constraints for (firewall rules...). The average latency should be very low (< 1ms).
- Another option is to use a dedicated OpenShift project. This leads to higher latency because the path is longer (VPN => Shared Services => VPN).  You need to take care of flows between regions as it is not because the machines are in the same project that the flows do not pass through another region. You must therefore set up an optimization of network routing through a tag that must be present on the MySQL machine. The latency in this case would vary between 2 to 10ms. Of course, this latency can vary because the flows go through VPNs.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your source and destination in the same VPC region, it will definitely reduce your latency. Even though latency is not only affected by distance I have found this documentation regarding [GCP Inter Region Latency](https://docs.aviatrix.com/HowTos/gcp_inter_region_latency.html) which could help you deciding your best scenario.

Now, going to your question, I understand you have created a GCP cluster and a VM instance in the same zone/region but in different networks (VPC) ? If possible, could you please clarify a bit more your scenario?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The important thing here is that we are using OpenShift on GCP and a VM not managed by OpenShift. So I am aware using same VPC is the advice but I don't see how to do that with Open Shift, i.e., tell GCP to put my VM in OpenShift VPC